# LIVE Video Streaming with Nginx + PHP-FPM / Process Timeout

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I have a live video streaming in my server using nginx + php.

the php file reas a live streaming and it directly sends it to the client.

I have only one problem. The problem is that i want each request to be in a new process of php-fpm. In a few words i don't want to have idle timeout for a process but instead i want them to close instant when a request is being closed.

With idle timeout i have huge problems which are hard to explain at the moment but i'm really sure that if i disable the idle timeout everything will be perfect.

Is there any way to do this?

**I'm using on demand php-fpm**

Comment: That's...a bad idea. If you get even a few dozen users you'll quickly exhaust the resources of all but the beefiest servers.

Comment: You think that the dynamic php-fpm would be better?

Comment: Without seeing the description about the huge problems, it is impossible to consider any solutions to the problem. Please add description of the huge problems, and why you think those are caused by idle timeouts.